# vector iterator not dereferencable when removing from vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a vector with a large amount of elements that get created and delete continously.
I want to swap the element that has to be removed with the last element and then use `pop_back()` to avoid removing in the middle of a vector but I
always get that my iterator is not dereferenceable and i don't quite get why this is an issue.

could someone explain what exactly is happening?

```
void EntityManager::RemoveEntity(Entity* entity)
{
    std::vector<Entity*>::iterator it = std::find(mEntities.begin(), mEntities.end(), entity);

    if (it != mEntities.end())
    {
        int pos = it - mEntities.begin() + 1;
        std::iter_swap(mEntities.begin() + pos, mEntities.end()-1);
    }
        mEntities.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: `I want to swap the element that has to be removed with the last element and then use pop_back() to avoid removing in the middle of a vector` May I ask why?

Comment: Because I have been told if you remove from the middle of a vector it shifts all the memory and it's inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` returns an iterator that points to the found element, which (in your case) is the element you want to remove.  When you calculate `pos`, you get the index for the element right after the one that was found.  If the found element is the last element in the vector, this will refer to the one-past-the-end element.  When you then calculate the iterator for that, you'll get the `end` iterator, which you cannot dereference.

You don't need to calculate the index.  Just call

```
std::swap(*it, m_Entities.back());
```

then immediately call `mEneities.pop_back()` within the body of the `if`, not after.  With the `pop_back` call outside the `if`, you'll remove the last element of the vector if the element you're looking for was not found.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
int pos = it - mEntities.begin() + 1;
```

is not needed. All you need to do is this:

```
if (it != mEntities.end())
    std::iter_swap(it, mEntities.end() - 1);
```